# How to open drawer navigator using button onPress event

Tags: react-native, navigation-drawer, drawer

I added a drawer navigator using **React Navigation 5.x**. Its working when swipe the screen. But i want to show it when i press on the hamburger icon in the Header section. Header is a separate component and drawer navigator currently placed in the app.js file as follows.

App.js

```
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

    function MyDrawer() {
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator>
      <Drawer.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />
      <Drawer.Screen name="Register" component={Register} />
      <Drawer.Screen name="Place an Order" component={Order} />
      <Drawer.Screen name="Place an Order_temp" component={OrderPage} />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
}

const App = () => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Header />
      <NavigationContainer>
        <MyDrawer />
      </NavigationContainer>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Header.js

```
const Header = () => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.child}>
      <Image
        source={require("../../assets/image/shared/logo-nav.png")}
        style={styles.logo}
      />
      <Ripple rippleColor="rgb(255,255,255)" style={styles.buttonContainer}>
        <FontAwesome.Button
          name="bars"
          color="#ffcc00"
          style={styles.barButton}
        ></FontAwesome.Button>
      </Ripple>
    </View>
  );
};
```

[currently drawer showing like this way when swipe the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VgFUX.png)

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue hope this help:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import {
  createDrawerNavigator,
  DrawerContentScrollView,
  DrawerItemList,
  DrawerItem,
} from '@react-navigation/drawer';

function Feed({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Feed Screen</Text>
      <Button title="Open drawer" onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()} />
      <Button title="Toggle drawer" onPress={() => navigation.toggleDrawer()} />
    </View>
  );
}

function Notifications() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Notifications Screen</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

function CustomDrawerContent(props) {
  return (
    <DrawerContentScrollView {...props}>
      <DrawerItemList {...props} />
      <DrawerItem
        label="Close drawer"
        onPress={() => props.navigation.closeDrawer()}
      />
      <DrawerItem
        label="Toggle drawer"
        onPress={() => props.navigation.toggleDrawer()}
      />
    </DrawerContentScrollView>
  );
}

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

function MyDrawer() {
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator drawerContent={props => <CustomDrawerContent {...props} />}>
      <Drawer.Screen name="Feed" component={Feed} />
      <Drawer.Screen name="Notifications" component={Notifications} />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <MyDrawer />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Comment: please add more description to your answer, like what's the issue, how you solve it, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a ref for your navigation container like this

```
import * as React from 'react';

const navigationRef = React.createRef();
    
<NavigationContainer ref = {navigationRef} />
```

pass the navigationRef to Header as a parameter

access navigation prop and navigate to respective screen as below

```
  navigationRef.current?.navigate("<SCREEN_NAME>")
```